# Deleting abandoned questions

Tags: discussion

Ref. [Voucher generated code giving store credit/userpoints](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14040/voucher-generated-code-giving-store-credit-userpoints)

User has not even visited the site (while logged in) > 6 months (I can see this with moderator interface). The one comment was never even responded to. Should these be deleted or just put on hold? I tend to skew away from removing content nodes, but wanted to check with others.

Comment: Isn't a question considered answered if it has one upvote? I would be more inclined to leave it open in case a future answer comes in.

Comment: *"Isn't a question considered answered if it has one upvote?"* Do you mean "if it has an answer with one upvote?" If so, yes.

Comment: Is there a possibility for moderators to accept answers for other users? In that referenced question, which is not completely useless as it asks whether a feature is implemented or possible, I feel that your answer could be marked as the answer. I prefer detailed and specific questions, but I understand that's not the case with most questions lately.

Comment: @musicliftsme - no, and that is by design. The OP gets to "accept" the answer which works for him/her, but literally everyone else gets to upvote the answers which work for them.

Comment: @benmarks, OK. I was just thinking of an alternative to abandon questions, to which the OPs will supposedly never come back.

Comment: Yeah, I wish this were an option, but I get Stack's perspective on it. They don't want to be the next expertsexchange ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If there is a comment under which means "please add info, we can't help you" delete it.

Comment: Delete the question or the comment?

Comment: What I mean is: The question is only answerable with the answer of the comment. So if the comment is abandoned, and therefore the question not answerable, delete both

Comment: Okay, that's what I understood. I've been going through old unanswered questions and doing this so that we can cull them later

Answer (score 2):

Is it a problem or bug, and is it reproducable? Keep it.

Is it a feature wish, or a wish for an howto? Keep it.

Generally I woult set the quality of the question regarding understandability as measurement here.

For the specific example, its understandable and a clearly defined featurewish, so it doesnt matter if abondoned.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion 'can I have feature X' questions should be deleted unless an answer is given that gives a good answer that is easily to implement for future Googlers.

If no answer is given it should probably deleted right away because it's unlikely it will ever be answered